# How does type aliases work in Go?

Tags: go, types

I have a type wrapper in my code:

```
package my_package
import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
type Server *gin.Engine
```

It works perfectly fine to use it within my package like:

```
func NewServer() Server {
    s:= Server(gin.Default())
    // I can call *gin.Engine functions on my s here without problems
    return s
}
```

In my test suite (which resides in another package) I import my package and get the Server type. However, when I try to call some "inherited" functions on it doesn't work.

```
server_test.go:68: server.ServeHTTP undefined (type my_package.Server has no field or method ServeHTTP)
```

What's going on?

**EDIT**

The solution I found is related to @jiang-yd answer below:
Change the type to a embedding struct

```
type Server struct {
    *gin.Engine
}
```

and change the "cast"

```
s := Server{gin.Default()}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in official document, there are two kinds of type, static type and underlying type. `Server` is your static type and `*gin.Engine` is the underlying type. most place in golang just use static type, so `Server` and `*.gin.Engine` are two types. check the golang [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types)

well it not help you in your problem. in your situation, you need [embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) struct of golang, which help you inherit all method from one struct to another.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up doing. I just needed some more understanding about go types.